# Meaning of "franchir un mur de briques par une porte"

Tags: sens, prépositions, verbes

From [Le Figaro](http://www.lefigaro.fr/jardin/2016/11/18/30008-20161118ARTFIG00128-david-austin-le-roi-des-roses-anglaises.php):

> Chaque jour, après l'heure de la sieste et avant celle du thé, un vieux monsieur et son chien franchissent un mur de briques rouges **par** une porte verte.

What does *par* mean in this context? Does it mean that the man and his dog get over the red brick wall through a green door? If so, isn't *franchir* a bit of an exaggeration, since they're not working hard to overcome the obstacle but rather simply walking through the door?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand why you have a weird feeling about *franchir*.

It can be used in both way:
 - In your case, It just mean you go from point A to point B through something.
 - Your other guess is right as well. Franchir could imply that you worked hard to do it. After a marathon, you can say : "le coureur a *franchi* la ligne d'arrivée".

To be short, both meanings are right so your sentence doesn't sound weird.